# JQuery datepicker with month update in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using a directive to render jQuery datepicker in Angular JS.

My directive has worked fine until I decided to incorporate the onchangemonthyear event of the datepicker.

When I incorporate this event into my directive, the date is changing visually when I switch to a different month / year, **but my ng-model is not being updated correctly**, because I see that a different value is being saved in the database when I save this information.

```
ERMApp.directive('angulardatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                });
            },
            showButtonPanel: true,
            closeText: 'Clear',
            onClose: function (dateText, obj) {
                if (jQuery(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                    element.val('');
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('');
                    });
                }
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                var currentDate = element.datepicker("getDate");
                if (currentDate != null && currentDate != undefined) {
                    element.datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, month - 1, currentDate.getDate()));
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(convertDateTimeToDatePickerFormatDDMMYYYY(currentDate));
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
            element.datepicker('setDate', ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
        };
    }
};
});
```

Any help on how to do this correctly will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since are you setting the view value manually on scope.$apply, you need to set the model value as well. Angular doesn't know it has changed unless an event is triggered to force it check the view

Comment: Its not working. The value is staying the same as before. @YaserAdelMehraban